# COBOL: How to differentiate between end of file and junk value when both have return code 10?

Tags: cobol

I am working on Fujitsu COBOL and there is a situation where I have to read the file and if there is a junk value then I want to abend the job.

When there is a junk value the return code is 10 but the catch is that when there is EOF (end of file) even then the return code is 10.

Please help me out on how can I differentiate between these two events based on the return code?

Comment: Hi! Please add more details about what you mean by Junk value. Is it a field, which you check for junk values? How the return code is 10 when junk value is detected? Is it a User set return code? If so, can't you change the return code to some other value (say 11)? Thanks.

Comment: @SrinivasanJv: Thanks for your interest!

There is an arrow received in alphanumeric field. We are reading a sequential file, read statement returns file status code as 10 when it reads the record with junk value. It considers file has ended and stops processing there only, leaving all the following records unprocessed. I want to identify the corrupt record occurrence and abend the program so that I can correct the file.

No, I can't set the code to eleven or any other number as it is standard code returned by COBOL on file read (end of file).

Comment: Is the file record sequential or line sequential?

Comment: @SushantRawat Is there anything missing for you in Rick's answer?

Comment: @RickSmith: I couldn't check the answer recently as I was stuck in some other thing really urgent! Sorry for the delayed response. Your query seems to be answering my question! Thanks for your time.

Comment: @SimonSobisch: Rick has answered my query correctly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On very early PCs (MS-DOS 1.0), a Ctrl+Z (X"1A") was used as end-of-file for text files. Your compiler is likely detecting that character and treating it as end-if-file instead of allowing the remainder of the file to be processed.

In the OEM/DOS character set, X"1A" appears as a right-pointing arrow. (You mentioned an arrow in a comment.) I created a short file with four records for testing.

The original file:

```
Record1
Record2
Record3
Record4
```

I replaced the "3" with X"1A". In a hex editor, it appears as,

[image: Hex Edit image of modified record]

Notice that the x"1A" character appears as a right-pointing arrow.

A wrote a program (not shown) to read the file displaying the output of the modified file.

```
Record1
Record2
Record
0003 lines read
```

End of file occurred at the X"1A".

The following program may be used to check for X"1A" and "identify the corrupt record occurrence ... so that [you] can correct the file".

```
   program-id. ctrl-z.
   environment division.
   input-output section.
   file-control.
       select in-file assign "ctrl-z.txt"
           organization sequential
       .
   data division.
   file section.
   fd in-file.
   1 in-char pic x.
   working-storage section.
   1 line-count binary pic 9(4) value 0.
   1 msg-txt pic x(25) value "lines read".
     88 error-msg value "lines read before cntrl-z".
   1 eof-in-file-flag pic 9 value 0.
     88 eof-in-file value 1.
   procedure division.
   begin.
       open input in-file
       read in-file
           at end set eof-in-file to true
       end-read
       perform until eof-in-file
           evaluate in-char
           when x"0A"
               add 1 to line-count
           when x"1A"
               set error-msg to true
               set eof-in-file to true
               exit perform
           when other
               continue
           end-evaluate
           read in-file
               at end set eof-in-file to true
           end-read
       end-perform
       close in-file
       display line-count space msg-txt
       stop run
       .
   end program ctrl-z.
```

The result was:

```
0002 lines read before cntrl-z
```

Comment: Hi Rick Smith! Thanks for the details. I was wondering how a junk value would let the `FILE STATUS` data item to store 10.

Comment: It's not a "junk value"! The run-time system considers the X"1A" to be the end of file, therefore setting the `FILE STATUS` to 10. All data following that character is ignored. The early systems used to write text files in fixed 128-byte blocks, so, even if the last part of the text didn't occupy a full block, the X"1A" would tell the program to stop reading. This was quickly changed to store the file length with the file name, but old files still existed. Some were ported from CP/M, which preceded MS-DOS by a few years..

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file for the use of Ctrl-Z to mark end-of-file.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code, I've just shown a method of differentiating end of file and junk value when both have File Status code of 10.

In the program, a file is being read. `FILE STATUS` for the input file being read is `WS-ST`.  Record layout is just 1 field named as `NAME1`.  I'm not really sure how a junk value (in your case) is causing the `FILE STATUS` to have 10 as value. But, in a way to reproduce the error you're facing, I've moved 10 to `WS-ST`, whenever `NAME1` field have `SRINIVASAN` as value. I've also broken the `READ` loop, when `NAME1` has got `SRINIVASAN`.

After the `READ` loop, the `FILE STATUS` data item is being checked. If it holds 10, another `READ` is issued. Here, I just came across `FILE STATUS` 46.

> 46 -  A sequential READ operation has been tried on a file open in the INPUT or I-O mode but no valid next record has been established.

Handling `FILE STATUS` 46 genuinely lets you know if the file has really reached its end. Going by this way, you can certainly differentiate EOF with junk value. Please go through the examples at the bottom of this answer and you may get some clarity.

```
ID DIVISION.                                        
PROGRAM-ID. EOF1.                                   

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                               
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                               
FILE-CONTROL.                                       
    SELECT INDD ASSIGN TO INDD                      
    FILE STATUS IS WS-ST.                           

DATA DIVISION.                                      
FILE SECTION.                                       
FD INDD.                                            
01 NAME1 PIC X(10).                                 
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                            
01 WS-ST   PIC 9(2) VALUE 0.                        
01 WS-READ PIC 9(2) VALUE 0.                        
01 WS-SWITCHES.                                     
   05 INDD-END    PIC X(1) VALUE 'N'.               
      88 INDD-EOF          VALUE 'Y'.               

PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                 
    OPEN INPUT INDD.                                
    PERFORM 100-READ THRU 100-EXIT UNTIL INDD-EOF.  
    IF WS-ST EQUAL 10                               
    READ INDD                                       
    DISPLAY 'READ FILE STATUS: ' WS-ST              
       IF WS-ST EQUAL 46                            
       DISPLAY 'END OF FILE'                        
       ELSE                                         
       DISPLAY 'RECORD' WS-READ ' IS ERRORED!'      
       MOVE 16 TO RETURN-CODE                       
       CLOSE INDD                                   
       STOP RUN                                     
       END-IF                                       
    ELSE                                            
    ADD 1 TO WS-READ                                
    END-IF.                                         
    CLOSE INDD.                                     
    STOP RUN.                                       

 100-READ.                                          
    READ INDD                                       
    AT END                                          
    SET INDD-EOF TO TRUE                            
    GO TO 100-EXIT                                  
    END-READ.                                       
    ADD 1 TO WS-READ.                               
    DISPLAY 'READ FILE STATUS: ' WS-ST.             
    DISPLAY 'RECORD' WS-READ ': ' NAME1.            
    IF NAME1 EQUAL 'SRINIVASAN'                     
    MOVE 10 TO WS-ST                                
    SET INDD-EOF TO TRUE                            
    END-IF.                                         
 100-EXIT. EXIT.
```

Several samples of Input and output are shown below:

**Example 1:**

Input: 3rd record is errored.

```
***************************** Top of Data ******************************
BHUTAN                                                                  
NEPAL                                                                   
SRINIVASAN                                                              
**************************** Bottom of Data ****************************
```

Output: Program ended with RC 16. Program didn't read further.

```
********************************* TOP OF DATA **********************************
RECORD01: BHUTAN                                                                
RECORD02: NEPAL                                                                 
RECORD03: SRINIVASAN                                                            
RECORD03 IS ERRORED!                                                            
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA ********************************
```

**Example 2:**

Input: No error record this time.

```
***************************** Top of Data ******************************
BHUTAN                                                                  
NEPAL                                                                   
**************************** Bottom of Data ****************************
```

Output: Program ended normally. RC 00.

```
********************************* TOP OF DATA **********************************
RECORD01: BHUTAN                                                                
RECORD02: NEPAL                                                                 
END OF FILE                                                                     
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA ********************************
```

**Example 3:**

Input: Error record `SRINIVASAN` is in between `BHUTAN` and `NEPAL`. Might be in the border between these 2 countries :) ?

```
***************************** Top of Data ******************************
BHUTAN                                                                  
SRINIVASAN                                                              
NEPAL                                                                   
**************************** Bottom of Data ****************************
```

Output: Program ends with RC 16. Program didn't read 3rd record as the 2nd one is errored.

```
********************************* TOP OF DATA **********************************
RECORD01: BHUTAN                                                                
RECORD02: SRINIVASAN                                                            
RECORD02 IS ERRORED!                                                            
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA ********************************
```

**Example 4:**

Input: Empty Input file

Output: Program ends normally.

```
********************************* TOP OF DATA **********************************
END OF FILE                                                                     
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA ********************************
```

Hope this helps!