# How to remove end-of-proof symbol?

Tags: cobol, dosbox, gnucobol

Every time I'm writing to an output file, there will always be an end-of-proof symbol (`□`).

Consider the program below:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. HEY.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT OUTFILE ASSIGN TO "alpha.txt".
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD  OUTFILE.
   01  OUTREC       PIC X(10).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       OPEN OUTPUT OUTFILE
       MOVE "ABCDEFGHIJ" TO OUTREC
       WRITE OUTREC
       CLOSE OUTFILE
       STOP RUN.
```

The contents of alpha.txt is

```
ABCDEFJHIJ
□
```

I'm using Realia because that is what our school requires us to use. I'm also aware that if I run the same code above using some other compiler such as OpenCobol, the output is just fine, i.e., without the the end-of-proof symbol.

So, **how do I remove the end-of-proof symbol?**

Comment: "I'm using Realia because that is what our school requires us to use." I *highly* suggest to talk to the instructors as Realia is (as far as I know) very outdated and GnuCOBOL should work on any system Realia works on.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certainly an end-of-file mark (Cntl-Z or 0x1A). On my system (Win 10) the symbol is displayed as elongated (tall) rather than square. Pasted to this post it is square.

```
ABCDEFJHIJ
```

[The square shows in preview and edit; but later disappears.]

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52546248/9170346) and this Wikipedia article, [End-of-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file), for more information.

> How to remove end-of-proof symbol?

Reading files in Realia COBOL is not a problem. It may not be a problem with GNUCobol. However, a character by character copy of the file, stopping at the eof-of-file mark, can be done in COBOL or any other language.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely no end-of-proof symbol in the file, instead the symbol you see is used for the non-printable character which is in there (or a character without a symbol in the used font; or, as Rick pointed out the end-of-file marker).

From the "txt" extension it looks like you want a text file but as you did not specify anything you end up with a sequential file.
I'm not 100% sure about the support for the (up to COBOL 202x non-standard) `ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL` in Realia COBOL, but I suggest to give it a try:

```
       SELECT OUTFILE ASSIGN TO "alpha.txt"
              ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
```